# lua wrapper type name is not allowed

Tags: c++, lua

Im using the lua wrapper called LuaTinker and Im very happy with it. But now while trying to call function from a class Im getting the error "type name is not allowed"

Link to the LuaTinker
https://github.com/zupet/LuaTinker

The error message is here:

```
lua_tinker::class_con<LuaFunctions>(L, lua_tinker::constructor< LuaFunctions , int >);
```

at

> lua_tinker::constructor< LuaFunctions , int >

LuaFunctions.h

```
class LuaFunctions
{
public:
    LuaFunctions(int val) {}
    ~LuaFunctions(){}

    int                         getpllevel(int playerid);

};
```

In the main class:

```
lua_State* L = lua_open();
m_luaState = L;
luaopen_base(L);

lua_tinker::class_add<LuaFunctions>(L, "LuaFunctions");

lua_tinker::class_con<LuaFunctions>(L, lua_tinker::constructor< LuaFunctions , int >);
```

Tutorial which I fllowed:
https://github.com/zupet/LuaTinker/blob/master/sample3.cpp

**edit: fixed it. Was a problem with the tinker (had an old version)**